# CKEditor will not show echo function

Tags: php, post, ckeditor, textarea, show

I implemented Ckeditor into my blog , and I have an "Edit Page". 
In that page I want to get the text that I wrote so I can obviously edit it, problem is it doesn't show up , like the rest of the text , here's my code after the connection etc. :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
$title = $row['title'];
$body = $row['body'];
$tag = $row['tag'];
$description = $row['description'];


}



?>


<html>
<head>


<title>Editare Postare</title>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

<form method="post" action="edit_approval.php">


Titlu: <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"><br>
Descriere: <input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo    $description; ?>"><br>

Continut: <br><textarea name="body" value="<?php echo $body;?>"></textarea>
<script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'body' );</script>

Tag: <input type="text" name="tag" value="<?php echo $tag; ?>"> <br>
<input type="hidden"  name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="approved">
<input type="submit" value="unapproved">



</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

valid html for text area is:

```
<br><textarea name="body" ><?php echo $body;?></textarea>
```

usually with `rows="4" cols="50"` but the ckeditor will have its own settings for this, but for fall back you may want them

Comment: This is not a valid code - the value of `$body` must be passed through `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: @Reinmar not true at all.

Comment: You're right. I said that prematurely. It depends on how data is retrieved from editor. Depending on that it can be already encoded or not. If it's not encoded, then it must be before printing into a `textarea`.